# How to prompt the user for input and only allow a numeric response (in Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working in Python 2.7. I want to prompt the user for input, and to analyze the input as a number. If the user inputs something other than a number, I want the program, instead of crashing, to prompt the user again. For example, I'm thinking (in psuedocode):

```
    g=input("Enter a number: ")
    while g is not a number:
         g=input("That isn't a number. Try again:")
    print g**2
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_integer(n):
    try:
        int(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

g=raw_input("Enter a number: ")
while not is_integer(g):
    g=raw_input("That isn't a number. Try again:")
g = int(g)
print g**2
```

Comment: That isn't working. When the user enters sss, for example, it crashes. However, when the user enters 'sss' (in quotation marks), that works.

Comment: Fixed. But does the input need to be an integer?

Comment: If not, replace all "ints" in the above code with "float".

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_number():
    try:
        a = raw_input('Please enter number: ')
        return float(a)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid number')
        return get_number()

print(get_number())
```

```
Please enter number: asfa
Please enter a valid number
Please enter number: asdfasdf
Please enter a valid number
Please enter number: 123.213
123.213
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` rather than `input` (since this is Python 2); otherwise it'll be `eval`ed before you even get a chance to look at it, which could do terrible, unexpected things.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't pay attention to python2, yeah ok changed to `raw_input`